# Prove that the angle $\theta=\arccos(-12/17)$ is constructible using ruler and compass.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, proof-verification

Could I just do this?

Proof: if we want to show $\arccos\left(\frac{-12}{15}\right)$ is constructible, can't I just say, take $x_0=\cos(\theta)=-\frac{12}{17}$ implies $17x_0+12=0$ which says that $f(x_0)=17x+0+12$ is a polynomial with root $x_0$. But $f(x)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion with $p=3$. So $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial with $x_0$ as a root, thus $\left[\mathbb{Q}[x]:\mathbb{Q}\right]=1$ which is equal to $2^m$ for $m=0$.

Comment: but couldn't we refine the argument to say that if, theta is constructible, then cos(theta) is constructible?

Comment: A brain fart, sorry! I was "certain" that the question was about constructibility of a regular 17-gon :_)

Comment: haha, it's cool.

Comment: Take $\theta=1$ for a contradiction, since $\cos 1$ is transcendental.

Comment: You have to be very careful what you mean by 'constructible' here, because it means subtly different things in different contexts.  If you mean the angle which is one angle of a right triangle with side 12 and hypotenuse 17 (which the statement using $\theta$ certainly suggests), then as Andre's answer gives this is quite straightforward - but the _linear_ quantity that corresponds to arccos(-12/17) is certainly not constructible; it's not even algebraic.

Answer (score 3):

There is a more concrete way: using Eisenstein to prove the irreducibility of a polynomial of degree $1$ seems like overkill.

We can explicitly construct a right triangle with one leg equal to $12$ and hypotenuse  $17$. So we have constructed an angle whose cosine is $12/17$. Now it is easy to produce $\arccos(-12/17)$.

**Remark:** For any rational $r$ with $-1\le r\le 1$, the angle $\arccos(r)$ is compass and straightedge constructible.

Comment: 5,12,17 is not a triple.

Comment: Oops! Indeed it isn't! But the triangle is still explicitly constructible.

Comment: there are no triples with such a property, there is only 12,13 or 12,15

Comment: @Crypto Nobody said that $(5,12,17)$ is a pythagorean triple

Comment: Well, I implied it.

Comment: @Crypto Let $AB=12$, you can construct a perpendicular $(d)$ to $(AB)$ at $B$ and a circle $(\Gamma)$ of radius $17$ centered at $A$. Then $C\in\Gamma\cap(d)$ so that $ABC$ is a right triangle

Comment: @AndréNicolas You mean for any constructible number $r$?

Comment: It is true for any constructible number. Every rational is constructible. I wanted to state the result for numbers "like" the one mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Regarding the remark at the bottom of your "answer": take $r=1$ when $\cos^{-1}1=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is transcendental, hence not algebraic, hence not constructible. Furthermore, there is a dense set of counterexamples, so the statement is rarely true.

Comment: Your clarification doesn't fix things. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConstructibleNumber.html. With compass and straightedge alone, you can only construct algebraic numbers.

Comment: Actually I am little confused. Doesn't OP want to have *a straight line with lenth $\arccos\frac{12}{17}$* not an angle?

Comment: The OP's question is not really worded coherently, but I'm just pointing out that the "answer" given here makes an incorrect claim. It should probably not be voted positively...

Comment: @pre-kidney Andre's answer shows how to construct an angle with measure $\arccos\frac{12}{17}$ not a straight line, I think.

Comment: The title of the OP's question asks about constructibility of an angle, not of a number. It is certainly true that we cannot construct the number $\arccos(1)$.

Comment: That's not really correct terminology; constructing a number means constructing a point at that distance from the origin.

Comment: @pre-kidney There's a difference between a constructible number (i.e. the length of a straight line segment) and a [constructible angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass-and-straightedge_construction#Constructible_angles).

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is with a triangle whose three sides are $51$, $92$, and $133$. Then Law of Cosines.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The above proof is correct though right?